# Setting a ToolTip descriptor to a complex DataField in a DataForm

Tags: data-annotations, wcf-ria-services, silverlight-5.0, dataform

I can set a Tooltip descriptor to a field by setting a [Display(Name="My Description")] to a property in the domain service metadata.

An example is:

```
[Display(Description="Type can be I (Individual), S (Store)")]
public string CustomerType { get; set; }
```

[image: example]

**But in the case of a more complex field, the tooltip descriptor doesn't show:**

This is the case:

```
[Display(Description="The territory the customer is in")]
public SalesTerritory SalesTerritory { get; set; }
```

Being the corresponding field definition (**SalesTerritory is bound to SelectedItem**):

```
<toolkit:DataField Label="Territory:">
    <ComboBox DisplayMemberPath="Name"
                SelectedValuePath="TerritoryID"
                ItemsSource="{Binding Path=DataContext.SalesTerritories,
                                    RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}}"
                SelectedItem="{Binding Path=SalesTerritory, 
                                        Mode=TwoWay}">
    </ComboBox>
</toolkit:DataField>
```

But the DataForm doesn't show the tooltip:

[image: Other Example]

I think that the reason it doesn't show is clear, but how can I overcome the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know you should use a [description viewer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.descriptionviewer%28v=vs.95%29.aspx). DisplayAttribute is specially designed for datagrid and not all controls make us of it. Something like

```
<sdk:DescriptionViewer Target="{Binding ElementName=myCmbBoxName}"/>
```

should work

Comment: Thank you for answering. You gave me the idea. The DataForm does work well with the DescriptionViewer, as my example shows with CustomerType, but we need to declare one of them for the DataField were the ComboBox is in, something like declaring a StackPanel inside the DataField with the Combo and the DescriptionViewer. we only have to work with the controls layout.

Comment: You 're welcome, yes, layout could be a little pain, what about an usercontrol consisting of a stackpanel and the combobox ?